# Using BigInt in React Native

Tags: react-native, bigint

I want to use a crypto library sign and verify a signature with Ed25519.
When I use https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-ed25519, it fails because of a BigInt issue

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): can't convert BigInt to number

[image: BigInt Issue]

I don't understand where it fails, can someone please explain me the BigInt behaviour in React Native ?

Answer (score 1):

It fail at `BigInt(X1) ** BigInt(2)`.

React Native transform this expression to something like
`Math.pow(BigInt(X1), BigInt(2))`, in which `Math.pow(number, number): number` only accepts `number`s as inputs.

You could wrap `Math.pow` to make the `**` syntax works again:

```
function bigIntPow() {/* Your implementation */}

function makePow(pow) {
  return function() {
    if (typeof arguments === 'number') {
      return pow.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return bigIntPow.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

Math.pow = makePow(Math.pow);
console.log(3n ** 4n); // 81n
```